# Importing contacts with custom fields only in Outlook 2016

Tags: powershell, mapping, outlook-2016

So I have a contact list in a .csv list that looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is import this list to my Outlook (Office 365). I started with creating the custom fields inside Outlook.

But I have discovered that it's impossible to use custom fields for mapping when Importing a contactlist:

[image]

This because Outlook does not allow custom fields to be selected when importing contacts.

I have tried using software like QuickPort and it does allow me to map the fields but it retrieves the contacts with empty fields only. This means I get x new contacts but all fields are empty.

Is there an alternative way to solve this?

I have checked to map custom fields using the Outlook API in PowerShell but haven't found any solutions.

Comment: looking at the value column in you picture, it looks like something is wrong with the input file

Comment: i think excel saves a spread sheet to csv using a semicolon as the delimiter ';' maybe you can check that outlook is expecting this delimeter

Comment: you can see the ACTUAL format of your csv file by opening it in a txt editor (notepad++ etc)

Answer (score 1):

It's as I thought. Outlook expects a comma delimited csv file. I think the file you are using is semicolon delimited. Please try the importing process again, but save your excel file  comma delimited  see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-contacts-from-an-Excel-spreadsheet-to-Outlook-f6483469-0684-4c30-82c5-c881930f5451) for instructions.

you can see the ACTUAL format of your csv file by opening it in a txt editor (notepad++ etc)

It seems you have to change your regional settings to make comma the delimiter. See [this](https://superuser.com/a/832794/244211) answer.

Comment: Hello, I also thought it was a problem with the delimiter but I use the semicolon method in the QuickPort program. It imports them all (I get the new rows in my outlook) but with empty data sadly

Comment: @KahnKah but did you try changing them to commas? a simple search and replace would be the easiest way

Comment: i did indeed. i think my problem is situated somewhere else tbh